# iOS debug error, debug certificate generation

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build my ios app in debug to test it i couldn't find a debug certificate so i used a development cert. 
I got this in the build

```
The provided provisioning profile and certificate do not match.  Please ensure that the provisioning profile you provide was generated using the certificate that you provide.
```

To skip validation, you may add the ios.validateProvisioningProfile=false build hint

Here is my actual configuration of certificates

[image]

I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you made these manually and didn't use the certificate wizard to make them. The P12 certificate information is also embedded into the provisioning profile so if you use a provisioning profile that was generated with a different certificate it just won't work.

You can enable that build hint in the build hints section if you want compilation to continue but it will probably just take longer to fail and will give a more obtuse answer.

A solution would be to use the certificate wizard and redo your certificates.

If you did this manually then redo everything. There are many nuances to making a P12 file and it's possible one of those was missed.